# Multiple texture colors on object

Tags: mesh

[image: Human Body texturing problems]

Im new to blender and am learning to create characters.  I modeled this using good topology all around.(I THOUGHT)  to my surprise when I added the subdivision modifier, and went to sculpt, my object has theses different color faces.  I can sculpt and texture on the surface just fine but when i go to paint it or render it I just want to make sure that this odd looking thing is not trying to prepare me for a future problem. Ive checked my mesh, recalculated normals, did a smart uv unwrap, prayed and, even opened up a new blender and copied/paste the object.  Please help.  I know its user error so please show me the error in my ways.

Answer (score 2):

I think these are face sets, as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlrgFS8AMMU&#t=16m30s) by Blender Guru, they are a kind of masks that you can create in *Sculpt* mode in order to delimit certain areas:

[image]

To remove the face sets you can select the tool again, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> left click on a grey area and paint on the colored areas. Or you can simply deactivate the option in the *Viewport Overlays* panel:

[image]

Comment: im so happy i reached out!  thank you Moonboots!

Comment: you're welcome, I've added a time stamp to the link to Blender Guru's tutorial if you ever want to know a bit more about Face Sets